# how to use the reduce function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can we get the smallest value from an array of objects?

```
const arr = [
objTemp1 = {value: 10},
objTemp2 = { value: 1},
objTemp3 ={value: 40}
]
function smalels(...obj) => obj.reduce(initial_value, value){
if (initial_value < value)
 return initial_value 
 else 
return value  } )
```

where is it I am doing the mistake?

Comment: where is your array? what have you tried? what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the min object using `Array.reduce` as follows.

```js
const objTemp1 = {
  value: 10,
};
const objTemp2 = {
  value: 1,
};
const objTemp3 = {
  value: 100,
}

function smallest() {
  return Object.values(arguments).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return (acc && acc.value < cur.value) ? acc : cur;
  }, null);
}

console.log(smallest(objTemp1, objTemp2, objTemp3));
```

Comment: Just skip the third parameter instead of comparing to `null`. It's a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

By having an array of objects, you could directly reduce this array and return the object with the smallest value.

```js
const
    array = [{ value: 10 }, { value: 1 }, { value: 100 }],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) => a.value < b.value ? a : b);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Derek.W answered it really well. My solution is also the same.

```
objTemp1 = {
    value: 10,
};
objTemp2 = {
    value: 1,
};
objTemp3 = {
    value: 100,
};

var allObj = [objTemp1,objTemp2,objTemp3]; //I took all the objects in an array

var smallestObj = allObj.reduce((prev,currentValue)=>{
  return prev.value <= currentValue.value ? prev : currentValue;
});
```